# how to autowire a static inner class in controller in java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have class class A which has static inner class i.e B. now i want to autowire class B in a controller class i.e C.
I have tried like below but getting unsatisfied dependency.

```
class A{
  public void methodA(){}
  public static class B{
     public void methodB(){}
   }
}

@Controller
class C {
  private final A.B ab;
  @Autowired
  C(A.B ab){
    this.ab=ab;
  }
}
```

Comment: just because A is a Component that doesn't make A.B one.  What if you put @Component on A.B?

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for prompt reply. So if i removed the component from A. should it be working ?